# AVPlayerLayer with alpha mask

Tags: iphone, objective-c, avfoundation

Has anyone got a video playing on an AVPlayerLayer with an alpha channel?

If so, how is it possible? I've tried many different solutions including using pure alpha channel video, applying blend modes to the target layer and animating every frame myself. The only workable solution is the latter and it bogs the phone down too much.

Comment: any news here? did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

i use mask,

```
NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: file];

AVURLAsset* url = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:fileURL options:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey]];

AVPlayerItem* pitem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:url1];
AVPlayer*player  = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:pitem1];

pv = [[PlayerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 100, 100)];
[pv setPlayer:player];

UIImageView*iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mask"]];
pv.layer.mask = iv.layer;
```

mask is png-file with transparency.

Comment: Yes, but your mask is a static image. What if I need the mask to be animated as well.
I know that you can have a frameset animation as a mask, but that is not what we are looking for is to play a transparent video and not a png frames